# Como listar subcategorias específica para cada página?

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria listar dentro da pagina categoria.php as sub categorias da própria pagina especifica, estou usando `wp_list_categories()` e tentando passa o id com `get_the_category()`, mas não estou tendo nenhum resultado.

```
<?php

$categories = get_the_category();
    $id = $categories[0]->term_id;
    wp_list_categories( array(
        'child_of'        =>  $id,
        'show_count'      => 0,
        'orderby'         => 'name',
        'title_li'        => '',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'container_class' => 'menu-footer-titulo',
        'hide_empty'      => 0,
        ));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A função `get_the_category()` retorna um array com os objetos da categoria corrente. Em seguida eu varri todos os elementos com o foreach armazenando os ids dos termos no array `$cat_ids`. Depois usei a função `implode()` para transformar `$cat_ids` em uma string `$inc`.

```
$categorias = get_the_category();
foreach ($categorias as $value) {
    $cat_ids[] = $value->cat_ID ;
}
$inc = implode(',' , $cat_ids);
$args = array(  
    'include' => $inc,
    'hierarchical' => 1
);

wp_list_categories($args);
```